# Set Post Private if no linked Post Objects (ACF)

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, post-status

I have created 2 custom post types (using CPT UI). Parent and children. Many children can be associated to one parent using a post object field(add_to_parent).

I would like the parent post type to be automatically set to private if there are no post objects (children) linked to it, and then once a child is associated to the parent, the parent then becomes published.

Any ideas would be greatfully received.

Comment: Maybe try using the [save_post_{$post->post_type}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) hook on your children post type to check if it's associated with a parent. And if yes get the parent ID and set the post as private using [wp_update_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/)

Comment: Thanks for this. The only other issue, is that the child posts can also be set to private, and so i would like the parent not to show IF there are no posts OR no public posts, so if there are private posts there will still be an association.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You're welcome. In this case you should also get all the child posts related to parent and check if they're private or not. For example create an array and push true or false if it's private or not. After use a function like [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if it contains a **false** like: `if ( in_array( false, $is_private ) ) {
    echo "Not private post";
}` and do the rest of your logic.